# Java Servlet - write data to file

Tags: java, file, servlets

I have a servlet which uses file with data. The relative path to this file is contained in web.xml.
I have following part of code, which reads data from file:

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
private Map<String, UserData> users;
public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();
    String userFilePath = getServletContext().getInitParameter("user.access.file");
    InputStream userFile = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(userFilePath);
    try {
        users = readUsersFile(userFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
            ....
            ....
    }

private Map<String, UserData> readUsersFile(InputStream is) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    Map<String, UserData> result = new HashMap<String, UserData>();
            ....
            ....
            ....
            return result;
     }
}
```

Because this is a servlet and it will not work only on my PC, I can't use absolute path.
Does anyone know how I can write data to the file, using a similar way?

Comment: What's the question exactly? You can not use an absolute path in your web.xml because you want to make it configurable? Or are you getting some kind of exception that you don't understand? You could write data to a file, just keep in mind that the servlet runs in a servlet container process that needs OS file write permissions to write in a directory.

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to write file to the server or client's host?

Answer (score 0):

If the resource URL is resolveable to an absolute local disk file system path and it is writable, then you can use

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource(userFilePath);
File file = new File(url.toURI().getPath());
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
// ...
```

This is however in turn not guaranteed to work on all environments.

Your best bet is really to have a fixed and absolute local disk file system path. The normal practice is however to store structured data (usernames/password) in a database and not a file.